# MatplotLib not properly plotting pandas timeseries 1 minute data after converting index to datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, time-series

I am having trouble plotting the timeseries 1 minute data after converting the index into a datetime object.

here is a chart before converting the index into a datetime object.

[image: VIX 1 minute data chart]

and this is the plotted chart after changing the index to a datetime object using
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

[image: VIX 1 minute data chart with problems]

I am not sure what is happening here, but it looks like Matplotlib is missing certain values when i am converting into a 1 minute datetime object.

Here is a sample of the data https://easyupload.io/koh8s6

would appreciate if anyone can help out.

Comment: it probably because your data is not continuous in time. like the data might ends with 5pm yesterday and starts at 8am next day, is it the case?

Comment: Not at all, the data is perfectly fine. I just checked it

Comment: Have you checked that your data is sorted according to the x-axis data?

Comment: yes, the data is perfectly fine and the data seems sorted fine. the chart is perfectly plotted when the index is just type string. this only happens when the the index is changed into a datetime object using pd.to_date_time.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work fine for me. Have you made sure to use a datetime type for your time index?

```
df = pd.read_csv('vixdatasample_to_SO.csv', index_col=[1])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.iloc[:, 2:6].plot()
```

```
                     Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 0.1   Open  Close   High    Low  Volume  ma  std  upper_band  lower_band
Time                                                                                                              
2021-01-19 08:15:00           0             0  23.03  23.01  23.03  23.01     0.0 NaN  NaN         NaN         NaN
2021-01-19 08:16:00           1             1  23.03  23.03  23.05  23.01     0.0 NaN  NaN         NaN         NaN
2021-01-19 08:17:00           2             2  23.04  23.04  23.06  23.04     0.0 NaN  NaN         NaN         NaN
2021-01-19 08:18:00           3             3  23.03  23.03  23.03  23.03     0.0 NaN  NaN         NaN         NaN
2021-01-19 08:19:00           4             4  23.05  23.06  23.06  23.05     0.0 NaN  NaN         NaN         NaN
```

[image]